# How to create enums using pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, enums, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin ver 1.18.1 for PostgreSQL 9.3. I want to create an enum but could not find any option in the GUI to do the same. Tried searching pgAdmin documentation as well but could not find anything.

Does pgAdmin not support creation of enums? If yes, then why and how it should be done then?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `create type .. as enum` as documented in the manual?

Comment: There is nothing wrong there and I did that as well to create enums but I want to know if there is a specific reason pgAdmin does not support creation of enums from UI?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I fired up a copy of pgadmin and noticed what you said, I couldn't see my 'types'.  If you pull down the main menu and go to preferences, then scroll down until you see Type, then check the box and refresh you screen, then types become visible.

Answer (score 13):

Just Create "type" in types option which is located in the schema section.While creating type just select enumeration type and fill your value in label

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Creating ENUM using pgadmin**:

```
Schema -> Create... -> Type... -> Definition -> Type = Enumeration
```

[image]

**Changing column type to enum using SQL**:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER column  TYPE <new_type> USING <column>::<new_type>
```

Comment: Should not be that way from PGAdmin creators

Answer (score 1):

For pgAdmin 1.22 and above, the path is

```
    File > Options > Display_Database_objects
```

scroll down to the bottom

Check or uncheck "Type"